# GeoLocation - Parsing //Formatted_Address?

Tags: ms-access, geolocation, vba, google-geocoder

I am playing with a new function in an AccessDB app to return Lat/Lon info from Hospital names.  The following function provides what I need when I provide a Name & Address.  I noticed (unexpected) the function returns a formatted address even if I provide JUST a valid hospital name.  I think I can exploit this to backfill address info into my database.

It appears that `Geocode.sRetAddress = .selectSingleNode("//formatted_address").Text` is "mostly" consistent and easilly parsed to grab Address/City/State/ZIP info using "," as a delimiter.  My complication is the rare occasion where a "Floor Number" is included in the formatted address string.  My parsing routine fails.

I found this routine (not mine):

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

'Public Type containing the geocoding of the postal address
Public Type tGeocodeResult
   dLatitude As Double
   dLongitude As Double
   sRetAddress As String
   sAccuracy As String
   sStatus As String
End Type

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : Geocode with Google Geocoding API v3
' Version   : 1.01
' DateTime  : 03/03/2011
' Author    : Philben
' Purpose   : converting addresses into geographic coordinates
' Parameter : No mandatory. string format or NULL
' Reference : http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html
' Remark    : Query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day
'           : A good accuracy is different of a good geocoding !!!
'           : Minimum delay between two queries : >= 200 ms
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function Geocode(Optional ByVal vAddress As Variant = Null, _
                        Optional ByVal vTown As Variant = Null, _
                        Optional ByVal vPostCode As Variant = Null, _
                        Optional ByVal vRegion As Variant = Null, _
                        Optional ByVal sCountry As String = "UNITED STATES+") As tGeocodeResult
   On Error GoTo catch
   Dim oXmlDoc As Object
   Dim sUrl As String, sFormatAddress As String
   If Not IsNull(vAddress) Then vAddress = Replace(vAddress, ",", " ")
   sFormatAddress = (vAddress + ",") & _
                    (vTown + ",") & _
                    (vRegion + ",") & _
                    (vPostCode + ",") & _
                    sCountry
   'To create the URL
   sUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" & sFormatAddress & "&sensor=false"
   ''XMLDOM to get the XML response
   Set oXmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
   With oXmlDoc
      .Async = False
      If .Load(sUrl) And Not .selectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/status") Is Nothing Then
         'Status code
         Geocode.sStatus = .selectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/status").Text
         'If a result is returned
         If Not .selectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result") Is Nothing Then
            'formatted_address
            Geocode.sRetAddress = .selectSingleNode("//formatted_address").Text
            'Accuracy
            Geocode.sAccuracy = .selectSingleNode("//location_type").Text
            'Latitude and longitude
            Geocode.dLatitude = Val(.selectSingleNode("//location/lat").Text)
            Geocode.dLongitude = Val(.selectSingleNode("//location/lng").Text)
         End If
      End If
   End With
   Set oXmlDoc = Nothing
   Exit Function
catch:
   Set oXmlDoc = Nothing
   Err.Raise Err.Number, , Err.Description
End Function
```

**Example Results (Geocode.sRetAddress - formatted address):**

good: 100 S Raymond Ave, Alhambra, CA 91801, USA
good: 3040 Salt Creek Ln, Arlington Heights, IL 60005, USA
bad:  4th floor, 2450 Ashby Ave, Berkeley, CA 94705, USA

**Question**

Any clue if the "Floor" component of the Formatted Address can be excluded, or alternatively explicitly return JUST the desired components?

Thanks,

Mark Pelletier

PS>  I am currently counting the number of "," in the string and conditionally handling the parsing task.  But As a general purpose approach, there will likely be other exceptions I have not encountered yet.

Comment: Counting the number of commas (or rather splitting on the commas and then concatenating) seems like a reasonable thing to do. If you can't show a situation where it doesn't work, it's hard to account for it for us.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide with a valid link?

Comment: Shahin, here is the link I found:  https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=206247

Comment: man.I have this same issues where our user would input address then floor number or office number, city and state eg 1st road parkway tower 1st floor, austin,tx. I want to eliminate the 1st floor. I am thinking that this will be uncontrollable issues if our dumb nurses keeps on entering invalidated address we also use a 3rd party geomap tool and not google. so we built everything from core while calling the geomapping api.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of a beginner in `XPath`, but I think I can solve this:

Instead of:

```vb
 'formatted_address
  Geocode.sRetAddress = .selectSingleNode("//formatted_address").Text
```

Use:

```vb
'Build an address:
Geocode.sRetAddress = oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("descendant::address_component[type='street_number']/short_name").text
Geocode.sRetAddress = Geocode.sRetAddress & " " oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("descendant::address_component[type='route']/short_name").text
Geocode.sRetAddress = Geocode.sRetAddress & ", " oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("descendant::address_component[type='locality']/short_name").text
Geocode.sRetAddress = Geocode.sRetAddress & ", " oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("descendant::address_component[type='administrative_area_level_1']/short_name").text
Geocode.sRetAddress = Geocode.sRetAddress & " " oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("descendant::address_component[type='postal_code']/short_name").text
Geocode.sRetAddress = Geocode.sRetAddress & ", " oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("descendant::address_component[type='country']/short_name").text
```

to manually build up an adress based on components provided by the Google Maps geocode API.

Note that if you're parsing things like cities and states out of this, that's a rather silly thing to do, since they're just available in the XML document. You're better of reading them directly from the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-read and it looks like your specific situation is geared to just hospitals so you will not need to consider all of the issues listed here.  I'll leave this up, though, in case someone else is looking to parse addresses containing more than just "floor".  And still--you could consider the algorithm for finding just the "root".

I worked on a similar project where I needed to identify the "root" physical address and it can be way more complicated than meets the eye.  There are SO many pitfalls to watch out for.  I ended up having to build a full-on rules engine.  Anticipate every possible combination and account for it.

-2 Main St 4th floor
-2 Main St 3rd floor
-2 Main St Unit 3
-4th floor 2 Main St
-Apt 3 2 Main street
-Apt 3 22 Rte 7
-2 Main st 1st floor
...many more

As a general rule you are usually trying to identify a section of the address formatted as "2 Main Street" where you have a number, a street name, and the suffix describing the street/road/drive, etc.  Here is a general algorithm which is only the base.  You'll need to expand.

If there are any commas, split the string into separate elements to be evaluated individually

Remove all punctuation in the address elements

Find index of the "Street"  You'll have to have a fairly extensive list, but here are some:

Road, Rd, Street, St, Boulevard, Blvd, Blv, Way, Avenue, Ave, Kill, Drive, Dr, Lane, Ln, Path, Highway, Hwy, BiWay, Bwy, Expressway. Circle, Cir, Crossing, Xing, Route, Rte, Rural Route, RR
I'm sure you can think of more.

Find the right-most instance of one of those and work backwards from that index until you find a numeric value (or, more accurately, the index of the beginning of a contiguous set of numerical values).
- Make sure that numeric value is not part of the street name (i.e. "3rd Street), which means make sure the numeric value is not followed by a "rd" or "th" or "nd" or make sure it has a space following it. If it is, keep looking back until you find the numeric part of the street address.
- Once you find the numeric value you will likely have what you need.  Grab everything between the numeric value and the "Street".

Other things to be careful of:
- Abbreviation for "Street" and for "Saint" are the same.  as in "2 St Francis St"
- Abbreviation for "Doctor" and for "Drive" are the same.  "3 Dr Jones Dr"
- "Route"s and "Highways" can have numeric values following them as in "2 Route 5"
- Abbreviations for the many incarnations of "Street/Drive" are very often buried in the street name.  "3 Caveman Arrival St"  contains "ave" and "rr" an "st"
- Numeric portions may also be written as a word as in "Three Main Street",

If you choose to try and identify unwanted sections of address instead of the desired section, you will likewise need to account for a plethora of potential situations:

Apartment, Apt, Suite, Ste, Floor, Fl, Unit, #, Flat, Box, POBox, PO, Building,, Bldg, Bld, Dorm, Room, Rm

Ultimately, you'll likely end up with many scenarios/exceptions you'd need to account for and many "Cases". You might also consider using regular expressions to identify them. Good luck!

Comment: this is my issue.if I start to put a dictionary of words or terms that they put after the actual address it is endless.